# Почему Kali Linux считают сложным дистрибутивом?

Tags: kali-linux

Такой вопрос. Почему Kali Linux считают дистрибутивом сложным? Почему есть такая точка зрения, что будто бы Kali Linux - это сложный дистрибутив, и что его могут использовать лишь опытные пользователи? Да, разработчики Kali, конечно, сами об этом пишут, но давайте взглянем на ситуацию *реальную*

Что это за дистрибутив такой? Чуть более стабильный вариант Debian Testing с прикрученными пентест утилитами. В остальном - тот же Debian. Ну или Ubuntu. Выпили из Kali пентест - и будет дистрибутив уровня Ubuntu. Стабильный (относительно), частенько обновляемый. Использует glibc (а не musl, с которым-то как раз бывают проблемы у некоторого софта). Сам процесс установки Kali Linux - весьма простой (это тебе не консольная установка Arch). Насчёт же пользовательского софта - ну, я лично проблем не испытывал никогда. Игры ставил (gnome коллекцию игр, если точнее) на Kali, компиляторы ставил, мультимедиа софт, все работало нормально. Может это "ошибка выжившего" (если это так, то реально, расскажите пожалуйста об обратных ситуациях, а то я даже не представляю таких ситуаций не то что на Debian-based, а вообще на glibc дистрибутивах)?

То, что новички сталкиваются с определёнными проблемами, это разве не проблемы, с которой новички столкнулись бы и на условном дебиане или убунте? Например, в своё время частая, ошибка на Kali - `GPG Error: NO PUBKEY key` при `apt update`. Разве этой проблемы не может быть в Debian, Ubuntu? В этом плане, кстати, особенно тупо смотрится совет "нужны пентест утилиты - прикрути репозиторий в дебиан или собери из исходников что тебе нужно". Простите, а разве это, наоборот, не сложнее, чем использовать уже готовое решение? Я уж молчу про поломку зависимостей. Я так однажды сделал в телефоне (Debian chroot) и долго жалел об этом: аж в какой-то момент захотелось на NixOS перейти, где нет хаоса с зависимостями (и да, на тот момент я уже был далеко не новичком в мире линух) (правда я там ещё репозитории Debian Unstable прикрутил, чтобы более свежий софт использовать, ммм).

И, чтобы не было голословных обвинений в мою сторону. Я этого мнения придерживался и когда был новичком а-ля "насмотрелся овербафера и тоже накатил термукс с метасплоитом", и сейчас, когда для меня поставить Arch Linux без арчвики - делов на 5 минут, когда я спокойно пишу на C и Python, учу Lua, спокойно работаю с BSD системами и собираю LFS.

Я реально не понимаю ещё с времён, когда я был новичком, на мой взгляд, предвзятого отношения к Kali Linux и его пользователям (даже опытным, которые хорошо знают Linux системы и умеют с ними особенно хорошо обращаться)...

Comment: (комментарий): возможно, лучше бы я задал это на ruMetaSO, хз...

Comment: Там это тоже оффтопик

Comment: На мете нужно задавать вопросы по сайту, а не по линуксу. Может вам также помогут здесь: [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы отсечь определённую аудиторию проще говорить о сложности чем о специфичности дистрибутива. Те кто не обладает хотя бы минимальным упорством самостоятельного решения проблем будут постоянно ныть на соответствующих форумах, даже по всяким пустякам, говоря о проблемах решения которых часто ищется в первых строчках выдачи гугла.

С другой стороны база пользователей Kali намного меньше чем в Ubuntu или Debian и при возникновении проблем получить помощь сообщества будет труднее. Да конечно, в 90% случаях проблемы в разных дистрибутивах могут пересекаться, но в остальных 10% они будут дистро-специфичны. И вот вы тратите время пытаясь помочь человеку с его проблемой, и не вы один, но проблема не решается и даже не воспроизводится, а потом вдруг оказывается что человек сидит на немного другом дистрибутиве и эта проблема для того дистра уникальна.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что проблема не в сложности/простоте дистрибутива, а в его аудитории (Kali весьма распиаренный дистрибутив и новички не просто так берут именно его в качестве своего первого дистрибутива), которая не имеет зачастую и базовых знаний Linux?,

Comment: @RandomDice779 верно, наблюдается так сказать "родовая травма", с одной стороны, вокруг всё новое и неизвестное(после винды), а также завышенная к себе планка(или самооценка), ну не даром же они себе осознанно сразу ставят дистрибутив для "хакеров", на что-то же уповают; а с другой стороны, сообщество видя наплыв "около нулевых хакеров" начинает с них стебаться. Вот и выходит, что для новичка Kali в отличии от других популярных дистров этот барьер взять довольно сложно как технически так и психологически.